# Migrating from Mulesoft to Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, mulesoft

There is possibly an option to export the Mulesoft assets into OAS / RAML file, which can then be imported into Azure APIM.
But is it even possible to extract all the relevant API specifications like API, Operations, Policies etc. that is needed by Azure APIM to create APIs using the OAS file / url import ??

I'm trying to find a way to migrate from Mulesoft APIs to Azure APIM based administration, but didn't come across a proper way of doing it end to end yet.

Any directions would help.

Answer (score 0):

OAS (OpenAPI Specification) can be included to Azure API Management by importing the definition file by downloading it from Mulesoft.
While migrating the API we need to make sure about API URL Suffix to our desired API Path.
Below are few steps from Azure APIM to add the OAS:

1. After creation of APIM, we can Add API.
2. We will be displayed with multiple options in adding the API like App Service, Function App, Logic App.

Refer to the [blog](https://soltisweb.com/blog/detail/2020-08-19-importingopenapiapiintoazureapim) for details steps in achieving the task of transforming API to Azure APIM.

Comment: Did this answer resolve your problem?

Comment: Not really. As Mulesoft side export for api only supports RAML format, which 1. Doesn't include all api details like definitions, policies etc. so all of that would need manual recreation on APIM side anyway. 2. Also, RAML to OAS again skips few more things. so, all in all, Mulesoft to APIM wouldn't be a straight forward affair.